# how to enable hidden list item programmatically in asp-net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want active one of my hidden list item programmatically in ASP.net MVC 5. I hide this item from html code and after satisfying a condition this item will show. How can I enable this item from my code. Here is my html code,

```
    <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">File<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("New", "Index", "Menu")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Open", "Open", "Menu")</li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="hide">@Html.ActionLink("Import Data", "ImportData", "Menu")</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

I need to enable the last item "Import Data" of this list programmatically. Is there any option like windows form as ImportData.Visible = true;

Comment: Enable it based on what?

Comment: Enable it after completing Open Action Method.

Comment: Open Action method will take you to a different view. Hidden field will be lost.

Comment: Do you wan't to unhide it on the client side or the server side?

Comment: I want to unhide it from both side after successfully completion of Open Action Method. @Owuor

Comment: for the client side, the current given answer by @Kumar_Vikas should work provided you are using JQuery, for the server side you will have to manipulate the view

Comment: e.g. pass the visibility boolean to the view e.g.  
                   
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("New", "Index", "Menu")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Open", "Open", "Menu")</li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      if(ViewBag.ImportDataVisible)
      {
                        <li >@Html.ActionLink("Import Data", "ImportData", "Menu")</li>
      }
                    </ul>

Comment: Exactly this one which I am looking for. And It works fine. Thanks @Owuor

Comment: You're most welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comment, @Owuor gave me the solution of my problem. Here, I am just re-arranging it for better view.

```
    <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">File<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("New", "Index", "Menu")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Open", "Open", "Menu")</li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    if(ViewBag.ImportDataVisible) { <li >@Html.ActionLink("Import Data", "ImportData", "Menu")</li> }
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Thank you again @Owuor and @Kumar_Vikas.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**Jquery:**

```
$('#importData').removeclass('hide');
```

**HTML:**

```
         <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">File<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("New", "Index", "Menu")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Open", "Open", "Menu")</li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="hide" id="importData">@Html.ActionLink("Import Data", "ImportData", "Menu")</li>
                        </ul>
          </li>
```